# remove or hide text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I need to hide some text (Add £0.20) which is within a td. I have a parent DIV class at the top. Here is the cut down HTML:

```
<div id="KitFormOptions">
<td valign="top" align="left">Text Personalisation, Add £0.20<br><br><textarea value="" name="KitGroupID_98_TextOption_796" rows="5" style="width:100%"></textarea></td>
</div>
```

the css path looks like this:

```
html body div#container div#body-container div#content-area div#content-text div#kitProduct div#KitFormOptions form table tbody tr.LightCell td
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap it in some element like `<span>` give it a class, and hide that element.

Example:

```
<div id="KitFormOptions">
<td valign="top" align="left">Text Personalisation, <span class="price">Add £0.20</span><br><br><textarea value="" name="KitGroupID_98_TextOption_796" rows="5" style="width:100%"></textarea></td>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('span.price').hide()
```

Comment: cannot wrap a span as its code generated and no access to source code

Comment: Ohh, than get the td content, write a regex that will simply replace the "Add ...(whatever)" with empty string. I see no other way. And then it has nothing to do with jQuery, it is pure JS

Comment: So basically you are saying that you can only edit CSS? I can't really believe that.. There must be some kind of 'server code' that you can access to, be it PHP, C#, etc. I think you are searching for a solution in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically wrap price with span using replace with regular expression:

```
$("#KitFormOptions td").each(function(){

    $(this).html( 
     $(this).html().replace(/(Add £\d*\.\d{2})/,"<span class='price'>$1</span>")
    )

})
```

And hide them

```
$('span.price').hide()
```

This replace any decimal format consisting  zero of more decimal numbers before dot and exactly two numbers after dot.
Therefore it will be replaced any price which will be on site.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following but its not a good idea. Better is to create a `span` around `£0.20` and hide this. But you say you cant do this.

```
$("#KitFormOptions").html($("#KitFormOptions").html().replace("£0.20",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why hide it? Can't you just delete it? Otherwise you'll need to add a `<span>` around it or something similar so you can reference it.

Where is the HTML coming from and why is the price even there then?

Comment: @PD24 you should put this into a span and hide that !

Comment: You'll need more that just CSS to hide this.. How is it created via code? Does it come from a database? Then remove it from the database. What kind of server coding are you using? You could write a script that finds the last comma and strips everything from there.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution can looks like: push your ", add 20" to span and set class="hide" for the span tag.

Answer (score 0):

A `div` element should not contain a lonely `td` but try this snippet, it replaces the text in all `td`elements within your `div` `#KitFormOptions`:

```
$('#KitFormOptions td').text('Text Personalisation');
```